# Is there any way to remove encryption from an existing Realm database?

Tags: encryption, realm

We are using the Objective-C version of Realm, version 2.0.2.  The database is currently encrypted and is in the field.

Intermittent crashes on the startup of Realm have been occurring, with an error message of "Unable to open a Realm at path ... Realm file decryption failed".  We are at the latest version available of Realm, and have not been able to find a solution.

We don't really need the database to be encrypted on the device, so we would like to consider removing the encryption.  Is this an option, and if so, how would we migrate the existing encrypted databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `writeCopyToURL:encryptionKey:error:` with a `nil` encryption key to write an unencrypted copy, and then move that over the original file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    RLMRealmConfiguration *confg = [[RLMRealmConfiguration alloc] init];
    config.encryptionKey = ...;
    NSURL *tempUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:"temp.realm"]];

    // Open the Realm within an autoreleasepool so that it's closed before we try
    // to overwrite the original file
    @autoreleasepool {
        RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:nil];
        [realm writeCopyToURL:tempUrl encryptionKey:nil error:nil];
    }

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:tempUrl toURL:config.fileUrl error:nil];

    // ... other didFinishLaunchingWithOptions things ...

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this sounds like what we need. I will respond with how well it works if we decide to take this route.

Comment: @user3768135 man, it's been more than 5 years. What happened?